# JQuery after AJAX GET

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX GET:

```
function edit(str){  
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("editaircraftdialog").innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
            $("#editaircraftdialog").dialog('open');

            $("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET","./edit_aircraft.php?icao="+str,true);
    ajax.send();
    $("#loadingdialog").dialog('open');
}
```

The JQuery code in edit_aircraft.php does not work. Here's an example:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#insertaircraft")
            .button()
            .click(function(event) {
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have had the same problem in the past and I cannot fix it.

Comment: As you're using JQuery anyway, why don't you use JQuery to do the AJAX request?

Comment: I agree with @EM-Creations, look into `.ajax()`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You likely have a JS syntax error. Is the variable `ajax` defined anywhere else because that's not a built in object.

Comment: any errors in the console? make sure jQuery is included on the page before the jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not load JavaScript with innerHTML. It does not get evaluated.

Use jQuery to your advantage

```
function edit(str){  
    var loading = $("#loadingdialog").dialog('open');
    var aircraft = $("#editaircraftdialog");
    aircraft.load("./edit_aircraft.php?icao="+str, function(){
        loading.dialog('close');
        aircraft.dialog('open');
    });
}
```

Comment: @user1972864 Either parse the scripts out yourself, or use jQuery html manipulation methods (.html(), .append(), .insert(), .insertAfter(), .insertBefore(), etc...) to append your html since jQuery does said parsing for you. However, even then it probably won't work because the code will be executed too early.